# Cannot store password using Git with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio

We are using the Git client build into Visual Studio 2017 (no TFS involved) to connect to a SSH secured repository. Almost everything is fine, but we cannot store the repository password.

I also installed Git Extensions locally. The password will be stored there via Credential Manager with no problems. It looks like VS is using the Git (or Git Extensions) dialog for login. Shouldn't the password store in VS work then?

Update: Git Extension and bash produce errors - the password is not stored. (Not sure if this is new behavior.)

Comment: you don't need password for ssh

Comment: what about connecting to your external repo via HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to generate SSH key on command prompt or Git Bash:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

See [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) and [BitBusket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html) tutorials.

Then you should upload key to your profile on the server.

How to do this depends on the server type.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get prompted for a password when you perform network operations from the command line (e.g. fetch, push, pull)?Did you set up your SSH keys so you don't need a passphrase? The password for HTTP(s) connections are stored via the credential manager, but I don't think passphrases for SSH are.

Comment: All I got to connect to the repository is the url (like ssh://git@10.11.12.13/opt/git/project.git) and password. Git Bash fetch produces an error (fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@ - but that's a different issue I guess). Git CMD fetches fine (asks for the password). VS works fine - but needs password, too. Git Extensions produce the same error like bash (I was wrong about that in my initial question). I don't know where to get a key from and I am not sure if and how it will work with my git server?

Comment: @TvdH, you need to generate ssh key and upload it to server

Comment: @Alexan So I generate a key (ssh-keygen?) and then put it where exactly? I cannot upload to the git server so can I just push the key? I have no admin access to the git server.

Comment: @TvdH, what kind of server? I used bitbusket, so I went to my profile and uploaded there. Ask your admin.

Comment: @Alexan: generating an ssh key and uploading it to server is the actual answer - if you care to post it as an answer, then I can accept it.